# Transiting through Incheon (Seoul), South Korea

Tags: transit, south-korea, seoul

I'm planning to fly from Ulaanbaatar to Melbourne via Seoul (and Kuala Lumpur). [There seems to be a policy for allowing passengers destined for some countries (Australia included) to transit through Incheon without a visa.](http://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?catSeq=401&categoryId=2&parentId=385&showMenuId=375) However, can I actually enter South Korea using this visa waiver? I'm hoping to meet a friend there for a few hours before flying. Also, would traveling via Malaysia affect this policy?

> **Transit tourists bound for another country**
>
> Eligible countries
>
> - Applicable to all countries (save for Macedonia, Cuba, Syria, Sudan and Iran) that are not granted visa-free entry into Korea.
>
> Applicable to…
>
> - Those with a visa (excluding Japanses Group Visa, excluding e-visa) or a re-entry permit for U.S., Japan, Canada, Australia, or New Zealand (5 countries) and traveling to any one of those countries through Korea.
> - Those traveling from any one of the five countries mentioned above, whose final destination is not Korea.
> - However, please note that the first bullet points are not applicable to those travelling to/from Guam and Saipan, which are unincorporated territories of the United States.
>
> Requirements
>
> - Must have a confirmed onward flight ticket for departure within 30 days after entering Korea, in addition to having no record of criminal offence in the five countries mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final bullet point gives it away. You can "enter" Korea for thirty days. (No one could possibly be expected to spend that long in the transit area.)

Travelling from other countries is not important or unusual.