# Stopover in Korea

Tags: air-travel, transit, transit-visas, south-korea, vietnamese-citizens

I am a **Vietnamese passport holder**. I'm going back to Vietnam from Seattle next week. I will have a half-day layover in Incheon Airport. I want to **go into the city - Seoul** just for resting, like getting a hotel and stuff. Do I need a Korean visa for this? If I do, where should I go and get it? How long will it take?

My U.S. visa is still valid. Also, I booked tickets from Vietnam to US already.

Comment: Korea has a very liberal landside transit without visa policy, described in [Transiting through Incheon (Seoul), South Korea](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48878/transiting-through-incheon-seoul-south-korea). It seems you would qualify, due to having a US visa and being on a trip to/from the US.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a visa.  You should apply at the

> Consulate General of the Republic of Korea
>   2033 Sixth Ave., #1125
>   Seattle, WA 98121
>   (206) 441-1011

They say it takes four days to process the application.  See http://usa.mofa.go.kr/english/am/usa/visa/Visa/index.jsp for more information.