# Chinese Passport Holder Transit in South Korea

Tags: visas, transit-visas, south-korea, chinese-citizens

A Chinese passport holder with a US visa has a flight scheduled from Beijing to Los Angeles in mid-November.

This person wants to go to South Korea for a 3 day conference; the conference is one week prior to the PEK-LAX flight.

If this person buys a round-trip ticket from China to Korea, **will the transit visa be sufficient? Or will they need a regular visa?**

---

Extra info:

What if the original ticket were modified to make it ICN-PEK-LAX?

[Some Transit Information Here](http://www.immigration.go.kr/HP/IMM80/imm_04/imm_p01/vm2.jsp). It says "Holding a confirmed onward flight ticket for departure within 30 days." Would a return ticket to China than a flight to LAX a week later be sufficiently "onward"?

[This question is similar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48878/transiting-through-incheon-seoul-south-korea)

Comment: @pnuts It is a single question about South Korean Transit Visas, asked a couple different ways.

Comment: @pnuts Is this better? more understandable?

Comment: @pnuts this tool is the best resource I've been able to find https://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=10101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link from Korea Immigration covers your questions, not sure why you need to ask again.

China is not on the list for a visa free 30 day tourist and transit stay, so that eliminates your PEK-ICN-PEK option (unless you apply for a regular visa).

Having a US Visa allows you to do a up to 30 day stay for transit, which means you must have a through ticket PEK-ICN-LAX.

The term "transit" by common usage in airport/immigration parlance means traveling from **A** to **C** via **B**, not **A** to **B** to **A** again.